# Fit div to content inside parent and right align

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div inside another div. Each of the inner div should right align, fit to content , start from a new line & wrap it's own content to new line as well. I'm using `float`/`clear` to achieve this as in the fiddle below. Instead of `float`, can I use `display:inline-block` with `right:0` to achieve this?

```
<div class="outer">

    <div id="a" style="background-color:#8f8;" class="inner">
        AA
    </div>

    <div id="b" style="background-color:#88f;" class="inner">
        BBBBBBB
    </div>

    <div id="c" style="background-color:#888;" class="inner">
        CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{
    background-color:#f88; 
    width:50%;    
}

.inner{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    max-width:100%;
    float:right; 
    clear:both;
}
```

Works with `float`:
http://jsfiddle.net/z6xuhLgL/3/

Doesn't work with `display:inline-block`:
http://jsfiddle.net/z6xuhLgL/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting `display:inline-block`, you make the divs behave similar to text, which means they will stay on the same line until there is no more space, and then break to a new line.

You can use float and clear as you suggested, but you can also just add a `<br/>` after each div to break a line:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div id="a" style="background-color:#8f8;" class="inner">
        AA
    </div><br/>

    <div id="b" style="background-color:#88f;" class="inner">
        BBBBBBB
    </div><br/>

    <div id="c" style="background-color:#888;" class="inner">
        CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
    </div><br/>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6xuhLgL/10/)

And don't forget to add `text-align:right` to the container.

I believe this is the simplest solution.

Comment: +1 for the tip. Before using floats, I was using the same trick in my design (using <br> or empty <div> with inline-block). I was hoping I'd find a CSS way of  breaking the line. Secondly, the `text-align:right` has an wanted effect of aligning the wrapped text to right. Agree on this being a simple solution, if I could align the div to right and keep the text left-aligned.

Comment: @click, you can add `text-align:left` to the inner divs to align their text to the left, if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

The `right` position is used to position `relative` or `absolute` positioned elements.

To accomplish the right alignment, simple add `text-align: right` to the parent: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/z6xuhLgL/7/).

You'll notice that the first and second div are on the same line, what may not be what you want. In order to fix that, you'll need to clear the sides, but clear only works on floated items. Therefor I suggest that you use your own (first) solution.

[**EDIT**]
As an alternative, you can use `white-space: pre` on the parent. You'll then need to delete all the white space that you don't need:

```
<div class="outer"><div id="a" style="background-color:#8f8;" class="inner">
        AA
    </div>
<div id="b" style="background-color:#88f;" class="inner">
        BBBBBBB
    </div>
<div id="c" style="background-color:#888;" class="inner">
        CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.outer{
    background-color:#f88; 
    width:50%;   
    text-align: right;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 0;
}

.inner{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    max-width: 100%;
    display:inline-block; 
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/z6xuhLgL/11/)

Comment: Didn't downvote, but that doesn't achieve what I want in http://jsfiddle.net/z6xuhLgL/3/

Comment: Please read what I write "*...what may not be what you want...*", I suggest to use the float method... since it works... or do you have problems with it?

Comment: Yes, I do understand. And as I said if you want to accomplish the same result with `display: inline-block` you need to add `float:right` and `clear:both`. So if it works the same, with or without `display: inline-block`, then why add it? I gave you an alternative by text-aligning the parent, so you don't need the float, but that has the disadvantage that they won't start on a new line.

Comment: @click, I added an alternative.

Comment: Thank you, just a little caveat though, the text wraps to the right which feels weird on reading.

Comment: Add `text-align: left` to `.inner`: http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/z6xuhLgL/12/ :)

Comment: +1, that's a nice alternative. Just have to dig up how well white-space plays across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

right: 0; as well as all the positioning properties should only be used when you've declared a positioning.

By setting display as inline-block, it will be formatted as an **inline** level box.
You will still need to use the float property and clear property.

http://jsfiddle.net/z6xuhLgL/4/

```
.inner{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    max-width:100%;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

Comment: If you still need to declare float and clear, then what is the use of `display: inline-block`?

Comment: I don't think there really is a reason in the original question to use an inline-block. Maybe he has other intentions with the `display: inline-block, but to achieve the desired effect, clear and float should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to accomplish that using `inline-block`.

Try using flexbox and you are able to achieve [**THIS LAYOUT**](http://jsfiddle.net/z6xuhLgL/8/).

CSS:

```
.outer{
    background-color:#f88; 
    width:50%; 
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: flex-end; 
}

.inner{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block; 
    margin-right: 0;

}
```

Comment: Looks good except that it doesn't work perfectly on all browsers esp. mobile http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox